# Eclipse Milo: History read with continuation point

Tags: milo

I'm running a `OpcUaClient.historyRead` operation which returns me a `HistoryResult` with a `continuationPoint` set. The OPC UA spec tells:

> When a ContinuationPoint is returned, a Client wanting the next numValuesPerNode values should call HistoryRead again with the continuationPoint set.

When looking at `ReadRawModifiedDetails` I cannot find any parameter for `continuationPoint`.

How can I submit a request containing the `continuationPoint` to request the missing data from the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I got support on the Milo mailing list I can answer my own question. The `continuationPoint` can be passed to `OpcUaClient.historyRead` by using the `nodesToRead` parameter:

```
new HistoryReadValueId(
  new NodeId(5, "Counter1"),
  null,
  QualifiedName.NULL_VALUE,
  continuationPoint
);
```